# Filter data frame by specific values R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, validation, data-science

I would like to apply a filter on my R data frame.
I want to select rows which value satisfy the next condition: 2^n = integer value 
Example. This is my data frame

```
pais    entidad    time_cases     v_doublingTimes
Mex      Mexico      0                  1
Mex      Mexico      1                  1.1892
Mex      Mexico      2                  1.4142
Mex      Mexico      3                  1.68
Mex      Mexico      4                  2
Mex      Mexico      5                  2.37
Mex      Mexico      6                  2.828427
Mex      Mexico      6                  3.34
Mex      Mexico      6                  4
...
```

As you can see I only want to keep the rows where their value is an integer.
Ijust want the rows where their value in v_doublingTimes is equal to 1, 2 and 4. 
I tried with this:

```
df$v_doublingTimes %% 1
```

This to know if I have integer values, If I get 1 then I know is an integer value but I don´t know why this is not working. The type of value of the row `v_doublingTimes` is float. Is there other way to filter my data frame and just keep the rows where 2^n?
n = 0,1,2,3... until the lenght of my df.

Comment: You should expect `x %% 1` to be `0`, not `1`, for integer values. Try `df$v_doublingTimes %% 1 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`df$v_doublingTimes %% 1` gives remainder when divided by 1

```
df$v_doublingTimes %% 1
#[1] 0.000 0.189 0.414 0.680 0.000 0.370 0.828 0.340 0.000
```

You need to select only the rows which has remainder as 0 so do :

```
subset(df, v_doublingTimes %% 1 == 0)

#  pais entidad time_cases v_doublingTimes
#1  Mex  Mexico          0               1
#5  Mex  Mexico          4               2
#9  Mex  Mexico          6               4
```

---

Other ways of doing the same thing :

```
df[df$v_doublingTimes %% 1 == 0, ]
dplyr::filter(df, v_doublingTimes %% 1 == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but I really don´t know Why the subset() is not working, even if try subset(df, v_doublingTines == 2) the output is null. Is it related with the type of variable of the row v_doublingTimes?

Comment: Yes, can you check what is `class(df$v_doublingTimes)` ?

Comment: Yes!  `class(df$v_doublingTimes `  is `numeric`

Comment: That is weird. Can you add `dput(head(df))` ?

Comment: `v_doublingTimes = c(1, 1.18920711500272, 1.41421356237309, 1.68179283050743, 
    2, 2.37841423000544)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: The `dput` doesn't seem to work but if I use `v_doublingTimes = c(1, 1.18920711500272, 1.41421356237309, 1.68179283050743, 2, 2.37841423000544)` and then do `v_doublingTimes[v_doublingTimes %% 1 == 0]` it seems to give what you want.